# Can't install Guest Additions using VirtualBox, Ubuntu guest OS, Win7 host OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-10.10

I'm new to VirtualBox and Linux. I've set up VirtualBox 4.0.4 on Windows 7. Successfully created a virtual machine running Ubuntu server 10.10 64 bit. I'm trying to set up Shared Folders. Prerequisite is Guest Additions. I've followed the Manual, as much as I understand it, and have Googled the heck out of trying to get past this. Here's what I've done:

1. `sudo aptitude update` 
   `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`
   `sudo apt-get install dkms`
2. Devices > Install Guest Additions... (nothing apparently happens, but I hear that's ok)
3. Devices > CD/DVD Devices > [peek at the dropdown: bottom line has Remove disc from virtual drive, so I think that means the ISO is in the virtual CD-ROM drive
4. Change to directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted and execute as root, so I:
   `cd ..`, `cd ..`, `cd media`, `cd cdrom`. (am I even in the right place?!)

I try `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
I get

```
sh: Can't open ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I try  `bash ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and `sudo bash ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
I get:

```
bash ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run no such file or directory
```

I try `chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` and get no such file or directory

It seems I'm in the wrong directory, the right files aren't where I need them, wrong permissions, or wrong commands. I'm totally lost since every troubleshooting point I've seen on Google either hasn't worked for me when it did for others, or I just don't understand the instructions. Thanks in advance for any help.

---

This is what `mount` shows

[image]

Comment: @Joe Fletcher - Are you sure you have installed Server? Server is terminal interface only. If you're new to Linux I would suggest "regular" Linux flavour

Comment: Yes, Server. I've been using the terminal. I'm developing websites. I'm not super new to Linux, but I only a few commands and such.

Comment: @Joe Fletcher - If you don't me asking, what do you need Shared Folders in Ubuntu Server for?

Comment: @Joe:  My version of the VirtualBox Linux Additions has two different `.run` files for the architecture of your Linux VM:  `VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run` for 32-bit and `VBoxLinuxAdditions-amd64.run` for 64-bit.  (You most likely have 32-bit.)  You're missing the `-x86` or `-amd64` in your examples.  Could that be it?

Comment: Seems like either the guest additions ISO hasn't been mounted or you're running `VBoxLinuxAdditions.sh` from the wrong place. Can you paste the results of `mount`?

Comment: @Patches so, I went to /media/cdrom/ and tried both:
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions-amd64.run
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run
both tries I get "Can't Open ...."

@Darius: It's so I can access thoses sites thru Win7 as well as Linux

Comment: @Sathya, should I just type "mount" in the /media/cdrom/ directory? (I did this and a lot of stuff came onto the screen) Also, how do I copy and paste from the Linux/VirtualBox terminal?

Comment: @Joe yes just type in mount. Take a screenshot ( Alt+ PrintScreen), open Paint & click on Edit -> Paste to get a screenshot

Comment: Here's a screenshot: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/n35eac/7)

Comment: @Joe indeed, the ISO isn't mounted. I've just reached work so I can't check on this right now. Once I get back home ( still 8+ hours to go!) I'll take a look

Comment: @JoeFletcher i also had so much trouble for ubuntu on win7.

Comment: @JoeFletcher i also had so much trouble for ubuntu on win7.
being pissed off, i started using OpenSUSE. now i am happy ... happy

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, seems the ISO is not mounted. Here's what you can do

- Ensure that the guest additions ISO is available to the host. You can do this by clicking on `Devices menu` -> `CD/DVD devices` and point to the GuestAdditions ISO file. The Guest additions is available in `Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` folder

[image]

- With that mounted, type in the below

  ```
  cd /media
  mkdir vbox
  sudo mount /dev/sr0 vbox/
  cd vbox/
  ```
- Now, the guest installation ISO is mounted as `/media/vbox`

[image]

- Run the Guest additions installer by tying `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: You're a genius! Worked like a charm. I ran all commands with sudo and re-started, and it seemed to work. I got 2 error messages, but not sure if those matter ([link](http://tinypic.com/r/o5nrkg/7)).

Comment: Quite welcome @Joe. You can ignore those messages, it shouldn't affect you

Comment: For those of you who are still having problems it might be you're missing the following packages: dkms, build-essential, and linux-headers-generic. [read more](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679)


try running: `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic` then reboot. After reboot mount the share like mentioned above.

Comment: Funny that there is no mention of how to mount /dev/sr0 in the VirtualBox docs.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: @EricJ. it's not _always_ necessary to mount - typically clicking on "Install guest additions" will mount the guest additions ISO - sometimes, this can fail however.

Comment: In my experience, 60% of the time it fails every time.

Answer (score -1):

If worse comes to worse, you can always install the desktop and use the GUI to install it...

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and restart.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all this.  Here is what worked for me. I am on 2011 Mackbook 10.13 Parrotsec Debian.  I had to be in Parrot Terminal and run the commands on this site
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/how+to+install+vbox+guest+additions+ubuntu
worked like a charm now I am up and running to finish setting up machine-geese it's only been like a month of trial and error to get the machine setup just to run NCL gymnasium.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125507)